# Function "patsubst" in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions):***

> `$(patsubst PATTERN,REPLACEMENT,TEXT)`
>   
>   
>        Finds whitespace-separated words in TEXT that match PATTERN and
>        replaces them with REPLACEMENT.  Here PATTERN may contain a `%`
>        which acts as a wildcard, matching any number of any characters
>        within a word.
>   
>   ...
>   
>        Whitespace between words is ***folded into single space*** characters;
>        leading and trailing whitespace is discarded.

***Now, given a makefile, is:***

```make
# The pattern for patsubst, does NOT contain '%'
foo := $(patsubst  x,y,x    x    x)
# The pattern for patsubst, does contain '%'
bar := $(patsubst x%,y,x    x    x)


# The variable 'foo', is a result from a patsubst-pattern, that did NOT contain a '%'
# The variable 'bar', is a result from a patsubst-pattern, that did contain a '%'
all ::
    @echo 'foo is: "$(foo)"'
    @echo 'bar is: "$(bar)"'
```

***Executing, we get:***

```console
foo is: "y    y    y"
bar is: "y y y"
```

So, it is obvious, that Make, may or may ***not*** "fold" all whitespace into one and single whitespace.

Or, did I do something wrong.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In fact all is explained in the [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions):

> Finds whitespace-separated words in TEXT ...

means that one or more spaces have to separate the words.

> ... that match PATTERN ...

means that it select only words that match a pattern (which can include some spaces).

> ... and replaces them with REPLACEMENT.

means that the selected patterns will be replace by a replacement.

---

A picture is worth a thousand words.

For `PATTERN = X`:

```
           +----  SEPARATORS  ----+
           |                      |
   +-------+-------+     +--------+------+
   |               |     |               | 
X  space space space  X  space space space  x
|                     |                     |
+---------------------+---------------------+
                      |
                   PATTERNS
```

For `PATTERN = X%`:

```
                 +----  SEPARATORS  ---+
                 |                     |
               +-+-+                 +-+-+
               |   |                 |   | 
X  space space space  X  space space space  x
|            |        |            |        |
+------+-----+        +------+-----+        |
       |                     |              |
       +---  PATTERNS  ------+--------------+
```

---

**Interesting thing:**

When you use the `%` character in your pattern, you can re-use it in the replacement, like this:

```
$(patsubst x%,y%,xa xb xc)
# Will be "ya yb yc"
```

But when you have space character in the `%` variable, make will strip them in the replacement.

```
$(patsubst x%,y%,xa   xb   xc)
# Will also be "ya yb yc"
```

---

**EDIT:** After reading the [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/?id=4.1), the interesting things are:

- [`function.c +146`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/function.c?id=4.1#n146): The function `patsubst_expand_pat`
- [`misc.c +337`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/misc.c?id=4.1#n337): The function `find_next_token`
- [`misc.c +325`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/misc.c?id=4.1#n325): The function `next_token`

So here is the behavior:

1. If no `%` in the `pattern`, this is a simple substitution (which keep the spaces).
2. Else it split the `text` by words and get rid of all spaces (using the [isblank](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isblank) function).
3. Finally, it does the replacement

Comment: Yes...Your final paragraph. It's easy to show, that contrary to `pattern-rules` and `pattern-specific variables`, Make accepts an **empty string**, as a match for `%`. Yes, `%`-matching rules, are not consistent across features of Make. And, can we both agree, that `%` matched (in my example) the empty-string, and only it. You sort of proved it :)

Comment: @JiCha To be clear, in your example `%` matched `space space` in the input string. And will effectively by replaced by the empty-string in the output string.

Comment: I strongly disagree. The rules for `$(patsubst pattern,replacement,text)` when there ***is*** a `%` in the `pattern`, are: 1)If `text` is empty OR rendered empty after variable-expansion, then, the function expands - *always* - to an empty string. 2) If, `text` is non-empty, then if it contains WS, then first split up words, effectively ***getting rid*** of ***all*** white-space, and then do - per each argument - the pattern-matching, where the matching rules do not require the `%` to match a non-empty string. Yes, it semantics, but it matters, as proven in last paragraph of your post.

Comment: @JiCha See my edit at the end. You are right, it effectively getting rid of spaces characters before to do the replacement when the `pattern` have a `%`.